# User Profile-Pic in file-system, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms

Project: I am trying to make a small website for my school bddies where they can store basic info about them. Have implemented [Scott Mitchell](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/storing-additional-user-information-cs)'s method so far.

Problem : I want to let user store a profile pic of him. Doing so by utilising storage in file system and saving the path in database.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

C# :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string virtualFolder = "~/UserPics/";
    string physicalFolder = Server.MapPath(virtualFolder);
    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(physicalFolder, fileName + extension));
    String ImageUrl = virtualFolder + fileName + extension;

    Label1.Text = ImageUrl;


    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;


    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string updateSql = "UPDATE UserDetails SET UserPicUrl = ImageUrl WHERE UserId=@currentUserId";
    

    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(updateSql, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPicUrl", DBNull.Value);

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

However I am unable to do so, I think part where inserting ImageUrl in db is wrong.

Further more the second time a user changes his profile pic the first image will be left in file how to delete it when a second image is uploaded.

Please Help..  Have been searching whole day for a solution and will be a great help.

Comment: Tip: You have not to close your connection explicit, it's done through the using/dispose.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing: string updateSql = "UPDATE UserDetails SET UserPicUrl = @imageUrl WHERE UserId=@currentUserId";
And also:  
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentUserId", currentUserId);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imageUrl", ImageUrl);

Comment: @C Sharper, can you plese show how to do it. Will be a great help.Thanks.

Comment: @Stefan : Thanks i will just try it. If it works and you were somewhere near i would havs surely given you a treat.

Comment: Changed the update statement again to use parameters, like for the currentUserId ;-)

Comment: @Stefan : Thanks thanks thanks, oh i was so much irritated and had started to believe that i should leave programming stuff, i can not learn it for if i can not do such a small thing. Thanks again.